# Website not able to access backend hosted at EC2 after SSL installation through Amazon Certificate Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, aws-certificate-manager

I have hosted my website on EC2 (both front and backend) instance and using SSL provided by Amazon Certificate Manager. I was able to access the route which put a "get" query on the EC2 backend before installing this certificate. However now I am not able to open this route, And the problem it is showing is that - Website is somehow not able to fetch data from the backend.

Also, this works completely fine when I open my website using the IP address of EC2.

I think I must do some changes in the certificate so that it could fetch the data from the backend. Please let me know what should be done.

I have been using React and NodeJS

Comment: ACM can't be used with instances. So are you using load balancer in front of your instance?

Comment: yes, I have been using the load balancer